# A varriable stored only one value, how can I stored more than one value?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I made a program in c by using Binary Search Tree but in my program one function name bill not given me the appropriate result 
In my main function I call a function bill like

```
  bill();
  printf("Total Bill= %d",total);
```

and actual def of this function is

```
int bill()
{
        if(root==NULL)
    {
  printf("No data found");
}
else
 { 
  char q[10];
  char a[]="yes";
  int sum=0;

    struct node *temp=root;


  int no;
   printf("Enter Id of work: ");
   scanf("%d",&no);

     if(no>temp->id)
     {
             while(temp!=NULL)
        {
             if(temp->id==no)
             {
            printf("Id: %d\n",temp->id);
            printf("work: %s\n",temp->work);
            printf("Charges: %d\n",temp->charge);
            sum=+temp->charge;
            }
            temp=temp->right;
  }


      }
      else
      {
             while(temp!=NULL)
        {
             if(temp->id==no)
             {
            printf("Id: %d\n",temp->id);
            printf("work: %s\n",temp->work);
            printf("Charges: %d\n",temp->charge);
            sum=+temp->charge;
            }
            temp=temp->left;
  }  
     }


   printf("Another Work? \t Yes Or NO?\n");
   scanf("%s",q);

   if(*q=='y')
   {
        bill();

    }

     total=+sum;
   return total; 
}

 }
```

in this last if condition when recursive function call another sum came and I want these two sum should stored in total and then return total but
 this total stored only one sum and return this.
so please any one help me to solve it.

Comment: 1) `printf("No data found");` --> `printf("No data found");return 0;`

Comment: 3) `bill();  printf("Total Bill= %d",total);` --> `printf("Total Bill= %d\n", bill());`

Comment: 2) `if(*q=='y') { bill(); } total=+sum; return total;` --> `if(*q=='y') return sum+bill(); else return sum;`

Comment: I do all three steps but when two sum 78 and 45 came so this give me this result

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. If it becomes a huge value than expected, Check if you refer to an uninitialized value.

Comment: If you would like further advice, Provide [mcve]

Comment: I do all three steps but when two sum 78 and 45 came so this given me

Comment: Also `sum=+temp->charge;` typo as `sum += temp->charge;`

Comment: In addition, I think your logic will not be able to trace all parts of the tree.

Comment: I want to say that when two sum 45 and 78 came , this give me the garbage value -194446464 some thing but in actual 123 should come. what I do?

Comment: What I can tell you is that you are making a mistake and need to fix it. There is nothing else to say with the information given by you.

Comment: As already mentioned, I guess that you are probably using uninitialized variables in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can return `array` in C. And in C++ you can return `pair`.